# Wrong fragment in ViewPager receives onContextItemSelected call

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an app that shows a few fragments (of the same type) in a `ViewPager` and I'm having some trouble with context menu items. (I'm using the support library).

When a context menu item is selected in the context menu in one of the fragments, the wrong fragment is receiving the `onContextItemSelected` event call.

For example, if I'm on fragment #3 in the pager, the fragment at position #2 receives it instead. If I swipe back to fragment #2, fragment #3 receives the call instead.

I've got a sample [here](http://rojekti.fi/files/ViewPagerContextMenuBug.zip).

(I'm currently working around this in my own app by having a `mHandleContext` variable in each fragment and enabling/disabling it when the page is changed. That way the `onContextItemSelected` call will go out to all the fragments until the right one is called.)

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with the support library? As a side note, this didn't happen when I was using ActionBarSherlock 3.5.1, which had its own fork of the support library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle onContextItemSelected in a multi fragment activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297842/how-to-handle-oncontextitemselected-in-a-multi-fragment-activity)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So this is some sort of idiotic design decision by Google or something that has just gone totally unconsidered. The simplest way to work around this is to wrap the `onContextItemSelected` call with an if statement like this:

```
if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
    // Handle menu events and return true
} else
    return false; // Pass the event to the next fragment
```

The compatibility library in ActionBarSherlock 3.5 had a hack like this.

Comment: @Seraph answer seems to be more correct, as soon as there is an explanation of this behavior. I had the same issue and solved it by using different groupID's (as in his solution) for context menus of different fragments

Comment: Arnt `hint`s considered to be non-reliable?

Comment: Theoretically, maybe, but both fragment adapters for ViewPager do set the hints.

Comment: Excellent thanks, I wasted my entire day to find a solution for my problem. I thought my Fragments were duplicated somehow and thats why wrong Fragment was getting called, now I know the culprit. Thanks very much, appreciate your answer.

Comment: If i inflate the menu from XML with MenuInflater I am unable to set groupId for menu item.

Comment: I can verify that the getUserVisibleHint() method is NOT reliable.  I have logs proving that wrong fragment is being called *sometimes*, but not always.  I am using A ViewPager, 3 fragments of same class, viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2), and My FragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: I confirm that sometimes this solution doesn't work. It is better to use menu item's ids.

Comment: will this solution also work on onMenuItemClick in Fragments as getUserVisibleHint  inside  onMenuItemClick  always return false

Answer (score 14):

It happens because of this:

```
public boolean dispatchContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mActive != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<mAdded.size(); i++) {
            Fragment f = mAdded.get(i);
            if (f != null && !f.mHidden) {
                if (f.onContextItemSelected(item)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, FragmentManager calls Fragment.onContextItemSelected for all of his own fragments until it returns true. In your example I can offer such fix:

```
    public static class TestListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private int mNumber = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> mItems;

    public static TestListFragment newInstance(int number) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("number", number + 1);

        TestListFragment fragment = new TestListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public TestListFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mNumber = getArguments().getInt("number");
        mItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        mItems.add("I am list #" + mNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mItems));
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(mNumber, 0, 0, "Hello, World!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getGroupId() == mNumber){
            Log.d("ViewPagerContextMenuBug", "onContextItemSelected called for number " + mNumber);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onContextItemSelected called for number " + mNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work.  item.getGroupId() returns 0 no matter what fragment is being long clicked.

Comment: It's a great idea to use the groupID for this purpose. That's definetely the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Oh Google, I mean WTF?

The problem is that *onContextItemSelected* is very generic, and it is called for each menu item of each fragment.

You can use *MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener* to force fragment menu to not use **all** *onContextItemSelected*, but only same function of this fragment.

Use next implementation:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    if (v == btnShare) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    onContextItemSelected(item);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.print:
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the only thing that will work if you use `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` in your fragment adapter. Also I think it's the cleanest solution.

Comment: Good workaround, Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Using intent for each of the menu items worked well for me.

```
    @Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextmenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = super.getActivity.getMenuInflater();

        inflater.infalte(R.menu.list_item, menu);

        for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ID, this.fragmentId);
            if (item != null) {
                item.setIntent(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MeniItem item) {

        Intent intent = item.getIntent();

        if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.getIntExtra(KEY_EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ID, -1) == this.fragmentId) {

                // Implement code according the item function.

                return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! In `onCreateView()` set `fragmentId = new Random().nextInt();`.

Answer (score 1):

The `getUserVisibleHint()` solution doesn't work for me - it always returns `true` even when the fragment isn't on screen. The `getGroupId()` solution doesn't work either when inflating the menu from an XML resource, which is my situation.

It seems that unless Android changes, any solution is always going to be a bit hacky. I create a global variable to store an ID reference for the current fragment in `onCreateView`. I then pass it to each `ContextMenu` `MenuItem` in `onCreateContextMenu`. When an item is selected, I validate that these two IDs are the same.

```
private int myFragmentReference;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Initialisation stuff

    myFragmentReference = 12345;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
    // Usual stuff

    int size = contextMenu.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = contextMenu.getItem(i);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("id", myFragmentReference);
        menuItem.setIntent(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = 0;
    Intent intent = menuItem.getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
    }
    if (id == myFragmentReference) {
        // This is the currently displayed fragment
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is a copy of @technik's. Also change `myFragmentReference = 12345;` to `myFragmentReference = new Random().nextInt();`.

Comment: In my use case I needed a specific ID (but obviously not `12345`) to correspond to the data displayed, hence why I did not use a random number, but I can see how that could be useful. Didn't copy @technik's answer but I can see the similarity so credit to them for getting in first.

Comment: Ah, understood. Excuse me. Nice that you got this solution yourself. If you wish, I will delete the first message.

Comment: Not a problem at all, it will be useful in certain contexts.