# wrong @Override Methods in fragments got called (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, overriding, android-arrayadapter, android-contextmenu

I have a problem using fragments.
First of all some basic Informations. I'm using an `Actionbar` (support.v4) with 3 Tabs / Fragments. The first two fragments cause problems. First fragments extends ListFragment, Second extends Fragment. Both has a `ListView` and one `ArrayAdapter` (different ArrayAdapters).

1. My Fragments:

   In both Fragments I create a `ContextMenu` (different menus / menuitems):

   In both Fragments I override `onCreateContextMenu(..)` and `onContextItemSelected(..)`.
2. My Adapters:

   Both Adapters override the getView method.
3. My Problems:

   - If I select a `ContextItem` of fragment 2, the `onContextItemSelected` Method of frament 1 is called.
   - If I update fragment 2, also getView of fragment 1 is called.

With your help and StackOverflow I already find out, that if one fragment is active the two fragments directly next to it are already active. So if both fragments have the same overridable method the first will be chosen. 
Problem is, I didnt find a Solution ;-)

Is anyone here, who understand my problem and / or has ever dealing with that, too?

EDIT: Source Code

```
public class ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    setContentView(R.layout.actionbarlayout);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager      fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction  ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment myFirstFragment     = (Fragment) new Fragment_ONE();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment mySecondFragment    = (Fragment) new Fragment_TWO();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment myThirdFragment     = (Fragment) new Fragment_THREE();
    ft.add(R.id.pager, myFirstFragment, "FIRSTFRAGTAG");
    ft.add(R.id.pager, mySecondFragment, "SECONDFRAGTAG");
    ft.add(R.id.pager, myThirdFragment, "THIRDFRAGTAG");
    ft.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
        case 0:
            Fragment myFirstFragment = new Fragment_ONE();
            return myFirstFragment;
        case 1:
            Fragment mySecondFragment = new Fragment_TWO();
            return mySecondFragment;
        case 2:
            Fragment myThirdFragment = new Fragment_THREE();
            return myThirdFragment;
        default: 
            Fragment defaultFragment = new Fragment_ONE();
            return defaultFragment;

        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
             return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
     }




    @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }



@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

}


            public class FirstAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<xxx> {

                public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        //SOME CODE
                    }
                };
                public FirstAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<xxx> items) {
                    super(context, 0, items);
                    // SOME CODE
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // SOME CODE: codeONE
                    return convertView;
                }
            }

            public class SecondAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<xxx> {

                public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        //SOME CODE
                    }
                };
                public SecondAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<xxx> items) {
                    super(context, 0, items);
                    // SOME CODE
                }

            public  class Fragment_ONE extends ListFragment{

                public Fragment_ONE() {
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.firstfragment, container, false);
                    setRetainInstance(true);

                    return rootView;
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                    mFirstListView =(ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    registerForContextMenu(mFirstListView);

                    mFirstAdapter = new FirstAdapter(myInstance, mItemsONE);
                    mFirstListView.setAdapter(mFirstAdapter);

                    @Override
                    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

                    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

                        if (v.getId() == android.R.id.list) {
                            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
                            menu.setHeaderTitle("CONTEXTMENU");
                            menu.add(FIRST_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 0, 0, "1");
                            menu.add(FIRST_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 1, 1, "2");
                            menu.add(FIRST_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 2, 2, "3");
                            menu.add(FIRST_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 3, 3, "4");
                            menu.add(FIRST_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 4, 4, "5");
                            menu.add(FIRST_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 5, 5, "6");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                        if (item.getGroupId()==FIRST_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID){
                        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                                .getMenuInfo();

                        int ListItemIndex = info.position;

                        Intent broadcast = new Intent(UPDATEREQUEST);
                        broadcast.putExtra(UPDATEREQUESTEXTRA, 1);
                        ActionBarActivity.getMyInstance().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(broadcast);
                        return true;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                    }
            }

            public  class Fragment_TWO extends Fragment {
                public Fragment_TWO() {
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.secondfragment, container, false);
                            setRetainInstance(true);

                    return rootView;
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                    mySecondListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.secondListView);

                    mySecondAdapter = new SecondAdapter(myInstance, myItemsTWO);
                    mySecondListView.setAdapter(mySecondAdapter);
                    registerForContextMenu(mySecondListView);   
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
                    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
                    menu.add(SECOND_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 1, 1, "1");
                    menu.add(SECOND_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID, 2, 2, "2");
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    super.onContextItemSelected(item);
                    // SOME CODE
                    Intent broadcast = new Intent(UPDATEREQUEST);
                    broadcast.putExtra(UPDATEREQUESTEXTRA, 1);
                    ActionBarActivity.getMyInstance().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(broadcast);
                    return true;
                }

            }
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // SOME CODE: codeTWO
                    return convertView;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Post some code that you made, we will try to help you with this. But right now, it's difficult.

Comment: are you using viewpager to hold the fragments?

Comment: Yes, I do. I don't have so much time because of Christmas. But I will put some code soon. Thanks so far!

Comment: Does no one has any answers, tipps or advices? It's driving me crazy! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Android FragmentManager handles overrides for contextMenuItem selection by iterating through all the Fragments, so each of your Fragments that handles context menu clicks needs to have logic for whether it handles the call or if the call should be passed to the next Fragment.

See this answer:
[Wrong fragment in ViewPager receives onContextItemSelected call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753213/wrong-fragment-in-viewpager-receives-oncontextitemselected-call?answertab=oldest#tab-top)