# ViewPager. Getting wrong cursor in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I am getting a pretty strange error(situation).
I use ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter 
with many ListFragment (one for each record in sqlite database).
Each ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.
I will show code snippets for
only more important parts(as far as I understand)

```
class EnglishDictStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int records;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public EnglishDictStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        records = getCursor().getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new EnglishDictDetailFragment();
        getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        long wordId = cursor.getLong(1);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(WORD_ID, wordId);
        args.putInt(LANG_TYPE, getCurrentLangType());
        args.putInt(WORD_POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        closeCursor();
        return fragment;
    }

    private Cursor getCursor() {
        if (cursor == null) {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(getContentUri(), getProjection() ,null, null, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    private void closeCursor() {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        cursor = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return records;
    }
}
```

This is a part of ListFragment class

```
class EnglishDictDetailFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private int mLangType;
private int loaderId;
private long mId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.english_dict_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        getSherlockActivity(),
        R.layout.english_dict_list_item,
        null,
        null,
        new int[] { R.id.english_dict_word },
        0
    );
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(loaderId, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mId = getArguments().getLong(WORD_ID);
    mLangType = getArguments().getInt(LANG_TYPE);
    loaderId = getArguments().getInt(WORD_POSITION);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(getSherlockActivity(), getContentUri(), null, null, null, null)

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (loader.getId() == loaderId) {
        ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).swapCursor(cursor);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).swapCursor(null);
}
```

It allows to scroll through ListFragments where is loaded right content.
But if I try to get cursor somewhere in code(on example in onContextItemSelected) with code

```
cursor = (Cursor)getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
```

I often get cursor from previous or next ListFragment in ViewPager.
I cannot suppose what is a reason but I see in onLoadFinished that that
method is invoked 3 times and somethimes last time there is cursor argument from other ListFragment. What I can suppose that firstly it use right cursor to show content but later there are
loading content for offscreen ListFragment items(neighbours) and some way cursor from neighbour ListFragment gets assigned to SimpleCursorAdapter of current(visible) ListFragment.
Can someone help?

Comment: Wouldn't your code throw a `NullPointerException` in the `getItem` method as you close the Cursor(and also nullify it) after the first call?

Comment: @Luksprog. I close Cursor in FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I just showed that code snippet to show how I instantiate the new ListFragment object for ViewPager. So there is a database request with cursor, data passed to new ListFragment and cussor is closed. Then that data is used to create CursorLoader for LoaderManager. There will be different URI for each ListFragment. getListAdapter().getItem(info.position) I use  within ListFragment, in onContextItemSelected. And I pretty clear see that there is cursor from previous page. But I see also right data in ListView on current page.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution.
It was issued in onContextItemSelected handling in a multi fragment activity.

[How to handle onContextItemSelected in a multi fragment activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297842/how-to-handle-oncontextitemselected-in-a-multi-fragment-activity)