# Context menu from listview adapter

Tags: android

I'm not entirely sure this is possible, but I have several activities that use a listview adapter. I want to implement a context menu on the listview items which I have been able to do using

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    vi.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle(sf.checkBusinessTitle(businessList.getBusinessName()));
            ....rest of context menu creation code...
        }
}
```

How can I create the onContextItemSelected from the adapter?

EDIT: I get the error "The method onContextItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MyAdapter must override or implement a supertype method" if I add the following to the adapter:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way you would do outside your `ArrayAdapter` implementation. In the `getView()` method, simply set:

```
your_context.registerForContextMenu(convertView);    // Supposing convertView is your View
```

And define the `onContextItemSelected` overriding method in the `Activity`, not in the `ArrayAdapter` extension.

Comment: So I have to add code to each Activity that uses the listview to handle the onContextItemSelected? No way to get one set of code to handle the selection?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do and how, but if you're trying to reuse the same `ListView` on several Activities it can probably be implemented with a `Fragment` or even easier defining a global function (in a class that extends `Application`) where you pass the `ListView` id and it overrides the `onContextItemSelected` method for that View. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok - have put it into a `Fragment` .. how do I retrieve the ID of the item in the listview within the onContextItemSelected

Comment: I think this is what you want to do, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297842/how-to-handle-oncontextitemselected-in-a-multi-fragment-activity