# App crashes on context menu selected

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, expandablelistview

I have 2 Fragments: Fragment_Master_List and Fragment_Trips. Master_List has an `ExpandableListView` which has a context menu, this is how I implemented it:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info 
        = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
    int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

    group_to_manipulate = arr_all_groups.get(groupPosition);

    // Show context menu for groups
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle(group_to_manipulate.getGroup_name());
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit"));
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, 1, "Delete"));
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ALL, 1, "Delete all"));
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE, 2, "Close");

        // Show context menu for children
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        bi_to_manipulate = group_to_manipulate.getGroup_items().get(childPosition);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(bi_to_manipulate.getItem_name());
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, 1, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ALL, 1, "Delete all");
        menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE, 2, "Close");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info 
        = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
    int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

    Group g = arr_all_groups.get(groupPosition);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    AlertDialog dialog;

    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:
            //do something to delete
            break;
        case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ALL:
            //do something to delete all
            break;
        case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT:
            //edit code
            break;
        }

    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        Base_Item bi = g.getGroup_items().get(childPosition);
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:
            //delete code
            break;
        case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ALL:
            //delete all code
            break;
        case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT:
            //edit code
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

So far this works. Now, in my Fragment_Trips I have a `ListView`, which also has a context menu, which I implement like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    MenuInflater inflater = Fragment_Trips.this.getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    trip_to_manipulate = (Trip) lv_trips.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(trip_to_manipulate.getTrip_name());

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

Once I click on a menu item - the app crashes and I'm getting the following error messages in LogCat:

```
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterContextMenuInfo cannot be cast to android.widget.ExpandableListView$ExpandableListContextMenuInfo
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.mycompany.myapp.fragments.Fragment_Master_List.onContextItemSelected(Fragment_Master_List.java:121)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:1601)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2008)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:375)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3521)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:924)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-26 20:10:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(9967):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 121 is this one:

```
ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info 
    = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
```

and it's in Fragment_Master_List, not even in Fragment_Trips...

Why is it happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: And now I wonder why was this question voted down? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189050/1231619) answer looks like I solved the issue. I had to rewrite some code: in Fragment_Master_List I changed the group for the fragment's context menu to 1:

```
menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit"));
```

I changed the `onCreateContextMenu` for my Fragment_Trips:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    trip_to_manipulate = (Trip) lv_trips.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(trip_to_manipulate.getTrip_name());

    menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");
    menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, 1, "Delete");
    menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ALL, 1, "Delete all");
    menu.add(0, Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE, 3, "Close");
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

Notice that the group here is 0.

And finally in `onContextItemSelected` in both fragments I checked for the group. In Fragment_Master_List I moved the problematic line inside the `if` statement:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getGroupId()==1)
    {
        ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info 
            = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        //rest of the code...
    }
}
```

And everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it loud and clear: The result of `item.getMenuInfo()` cannot be casted to `ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo`.

Do you have a `ListView` or an `ExpandableListView`? Obviously the menu info is only an instance of ExpandableListContextMenuInfo for an ExpandableListView, not for a regular ListView.

Comment: But how do I fix it then? If I remove the cast - I have a cast error and a suggestion to add the cast to `(ExpandableListContextMenuInfo)`.

Comment: I have a `ListView` in Fragment_Trips and `ExpandableListView` in Fragment_Master_List.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at the line that throws the exception and inspect item.mMenuInfo (I guess it has to be named like this) to find out the actual type of the value getMenuInfo() returns.

Comment: I'm just getting a `info cannot be resolved to a variable` on that line, and in value `"<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>`. I still wonder, how come I'm getting an exception in Fragment_Master_List when calling for context menu from Fragment_Trips?

Comment: I found a solution, posted an answer. Thanks for trying to help me, appreciate it!